# I can't calculate the total in React using a filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table in my database and I am trying to calculate the total in my react application.
The problem is that when I use a filter I get back not a number (NaN)

I need to show the total price when applying the different filters.

What I tried was to define a function like this:

```
const [totalRevenue, setTotalRevenue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("songs", songs);
    const total = songs.reduce((acc, song) => {
      const n = Number(song.Revenue);
      return isNaN(n) ? acc : acc + n;
    }, 0);
    setTotalRevenue(total);
  }, [songs]);
```

The filter looks something like this:

```
const displaySongs = songs
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + songsPerPage)
    .filter((song) => {
      let keepSong = true;
      keepSong &&=
        filterDistributor === "" || totalRevenue === "" ||
        song.Distributor?.toLowerCase().includes(
          filterDistributor.toLowerCase() || song.Distributor?.Revenue?.toLowerCase().includes(totalRevenue.toLowerCase())
        );

      return keepSong;
    })
    .map((song) => {

      return (
        <tr className="font-medium bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
          <td className="py-2 px-4 text-left">{song.Distributor}</td>
          <td className="py-2 px-4 text-left">{song.Revenue}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

return (
      <div>
     <div className="flex w-full">
            <select
              id="Labels"
              className="bg-slate-900 text-white border border-gray-500 text-sm focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
              value={filterDistributor || totalRevenue}
              onChange={(e) => setFilterDistributor(e.target.value) || setTotalRevenue(e.target.value)}
            >
              <option value="">Choose a Distributor</option>
              {[...new Set(songs.map((song) => song.Distributor))].map(
                (Distributor) => (
                  <option key={Distributor} value={Distributor}>
                    {Distributor}
                  </option>
                )
              )}
            </select>
          </div>

<div className="w-96 p-6 my-10 gap-4 shadow-md rounded-md bg-slate-900 text-center">
          <p className="font-normal text-white dark:text-gray-400">
            Total Revenue:
          </p>
          <p className="text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-white dark:text-white">
            {Math.round(totalRevenue).toFixed(2)} €
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Unfortunately, as mentioned above, this function returns an invalid value.

Here is an example of my data which is the same as you get when console logging:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "Period From": "2021-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Period To": "2021-02-27T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Transaction Date": null,
    "Distributor": "DistriburName",
    "UPC": "UpcNumber",
    "Cat. No.": "CaNumber",
    "ISRC": "CaNumber",
    "Label": "LabelName",
    "Release Title": "ReleaseTitle",
    "Track Title": "TrackTitle",
    "Mix Name": "Original Mix",
    "Artist": "ArtistName",
    "Content Type": "Asset",
    "Delivery Method": "Non-Interactive Stream",
    "Territory": "US",
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Revenue": 0.001091
  }
]
```

Comment: what are you trying to calculate? the revenue or the number of songs?

Comment: Why did you delete the old question and asked the same one?

Comment: Could you show us an example of songs array, the result you get and the expected result?

Comment: @Konrad because a user vote for the question to be deleted, as I didn't provide my JSON example.

Comment: @shehzad-ahmed I'm trying to calculate the revenue of the songs but only when using the filter. If I don't use the filter I see the total amount but as soon as I try to filter it for example by Distributor I get NaN

Answer (score -2):

Its because you are using the reduce function wrong.

here is something you can try:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("songs", songs);
    const total = songs.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
       if(isNaN(cur.Revenue)){
         console.log("is not a number")
         return prev
       }
       return prev + cur.Revenue
    }, 0);
    setTotalRevenue(total);
}, [songs]);
```

reference: https://ibb.co/4R73VSj

check the updated answer, just so u know, NaN is a number and when u convert any string to Number you cannot check if its a number or not after because it will always be a number, cause NaN is a number try doing this

```
console.log(isNaN(NaN))
```

it will return true

Comment: How is your code different from the one in the post?

Comment: i think this condition is wrong:

return isNaN(n) ? acc : acc + n;

Comment: Why? The condition looks alright to me. If song.Revenue conversion to a Number somehow results in NaN (not a number), ignore it and continue with the next song.

Comment: you are checking if the current value is a number than ur just returning the current value. and adding it if its not a number, that's why its returning NaN

Comment: No, the code is: if the current value is NOT a number, return old carried over value. Otherwise add current to carried and return the result.

Comment: Thank you so much @shehzad-ahmed tried your useEffect but I keep getting NaN when using the filter.

Comment: you are using it wrong, isNaN(NaN) returns true.

Comment: I have updated my answer with this NaN example,

Comment: @shehzad-ahmed yes, NaN is returning true, how to fix it?

Comment: check the screenshot reference ive added, just use that code bro.